# SQL Server RegEx Editing Text pasted from Excel

Tags: sql-server, regex

I find myself pasting information from Excel to be inserted into the company DB very often. I also noticed that when I copy/paste data from Excel into SQL Server DBMS, that the info is tab delimited. I need to get this formatted quickly to insert it into the DB.

MS's Find and replace RegEx confuses me and I am wondering if I can do a find and replace on this pasted text to format it for insertion.

When I paste, it looks something like this:

(BeginningOfLine)it-IT(Tab)TranslationToEnglish(Tab)ItalianPhrase(CarriageReturn)

And I need it to end up like this:
("it-IT","TranslationToEnglish","ItalianPhrase"),

Comment: Have you tried SSIS?

Comment: If you are doing this as a routine then, the best option is as @JiggsJedi suggested `SSIS`. You can give it a try [SSIS Sample](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/moving-data-from-excel-to-sql-server-10-steps-to-follow/)

Comment: Thank you for the response, this could be useful. Although I figured out that I can just use a formula in the excel to concatenate (with some extra bits in between) each column in a row into another column at the end that contains the string I ultimately wanted.